# Stuck on contract creation in remix

Tags: solidity, remix, smart-contract-wallets

there,
I am using remix on chrome browser to deploy my smart contract. But when I click on deploy button. It is written on terminal that" creation of SimpleStorage is pending" and it is stuck on this phase. What I am do? PLease help
[image]

Comment: Which network are u connected to!? Show us the left side

Comment: I am using Javasript VM

Comment: Okay what u could try is to use another compiler version or try it in another browser